# Execute two functions in return render react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to execute two functions in my render  method by conditional checks.

Example of my code:

```
render() {
   return (
     {!this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value && 
       this.renderResults()}
     {!this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value && 
       this.renderButton()}
   )
}
```

I guess this is not the best way. I don't like repeating condition.
Notice I can't place one func in other one.

Comment: why are you creating 2 functions for rendering results and button? can't you use child components?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in a container (such as `div` or [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html%E2%9A%A0%EF%B8%8F)).

```
render() {
   const shouldRender = !this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value;
   return (
     <div>
       {shouldRender && this.renderResults()}
       {shouldRender && this.renderButton()}
     </div>
   )
}
```

⚠️ *I only created `shouldRender` variable to make the `render` more readable for demonstrative purpose only. It's not required.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way, no harm in that. Just that I see too many conditions to render in one function. But anyway, here is what you can do. And You were missing base element inside your return.

```
render() {
   const condition = !this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value;

   return (
     <div>
         {condition && this.renderResults()}
         {condition && this.renderButton()}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: why condition2?

Comment: I assumed, he mistyped the second condition and introduced bang in front of it too. Was thinking in terms of ternary. Nevertheless, corrected it

Comment: maybe but he mentioned that he doesn't like repeating condition so i guess there is only one condition.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks very sweet of you

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're trying to do here but you'll need to wrap your conditionals in an element like a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

```
render() {
   return (
      <div>
         {!this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value && 
           this.renderResults()}
         {!this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value && 
           this.renderButton()}
      </div>
   )
}
```

That being said, you should consider revisiting how your logic works here because each statement is the same. Without having a better idea of what you're trying to do here I would consider moving your logic to each function. This is a quick and dirty version but will give you the idea.

```
 shouldRender() {
    return !this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value
 }

 renderButton = () => {
    if(this.shouldRender()) console.log('button')
 }

 renderResults = () => {
    if(this.shouldRender()) console.log('results')
 }


render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderResults()}
                {this.renderButton()}
            </div>
        )  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your both function in div. if condition fails you can return null so react doesn't render anything.

```
render() {
   return !this.state.isLoading && isFilled && this.state.value ? (
       <div>
           { this.renderResults() } 
           { this.renderButton() }
       </div>
    ) : null;
}
```